# Get bluetooth public MAC address from capacitor app

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, capacitor

I have capacitor app that needs to access Androids bluetooth Mac address for calculating command signature.
Im not sure if this is possible.

I tried Device.getId() but identifier is different than mac address my bluetooth device recieves from phone.